# how to execute multi-threaded application as thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have Java multi-threaded application which invokes one or more jobs(java code) using threads. This application has scheduled in cron tab and one or more instances of this application got invoked in particular point time. It works well. In this case, it invoked as process.

Now, I've requirement to execute this application as thread. I have some questions to be clarified

1. which is good method to execute a multi-threaded application, using threads or process?
2. what are the bottle-necks to convert multi-threaded application to be fit into single threaded model?
3. This multi-threaded application has single-ton patten. If simultaneously, two threads invokes this multi-threaded application from single threaded model then ( assume synchronization present ) will it create any threads issues Or this single-ton pattens needs to be removed?

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I had to do exactly this task - for this purposes I used [nailgun](http://www.martiansoftware.com/nailgun/).
It's an old software, but can do the job very well.
You will have only one `JVM` and each `java` program will run inside it, instead of a separate `jvm`.

**EDIT:** You does not need to modify you program to use with `nailgun`, even with singleton pattern since, as I remember, for each task(program) it use a separate classloader(be careful with memory leaks).